# Converting foreach using Babel

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs

I wrote a script [here](http://pastebin.com/SPMmmA4R), that I need to convert from es6 to es5. I wanted to use this opportunity to try out babel, however, I'm running into some issues.

The biggest problem in my code is the foreach:

```
obj.forEach(block => {
 //stuff here
});
```

However, after installing babel and using the command: **babel myCode.js -o outFile.js**

It doesn't change the foreach. Am I doing something wrong? Is there a way to convert foreach lines using babel?

Comment: It's nothing to do with `forEach`. Have you installed the ES2015 preset and put it in `.babelrc`?

Comment: yes, and running: babel myData.js -o dataOut.js --presets es2015 . Also did not change it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are not using es2015 preset.

Install es2015 preset package:

```
npm install babel-preset-es2015
```

Run babel, using this command:

```
babel myCode.js -o outFile.js --presets es2015
```

Or, instead of using `--presets es2015` param every time, you can add these code to `.babelrc` file:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015"]
}
```

Comment: I had it installed, I just wasn't using the --presets es2015. I'll give that a shot, thanks

Comment: I don't think `forEach` is converted into `for` even with preset es2015. Tried it on https://babeljs.io/repl

Comment: @AkanshGulati is right. You have to use the https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-loop-optimizer to transpile loops also. 

If you don't know what Babel is going to do with your code, use https://babeljs.io/repl. Here you can set plugins, es-Versions, etc.